# ngx-translate NOT working on iOS

Tags: ios, angular, ionic-framework, ngx-translate

I though it was recent but turns out it's not coming from my app, or there is a particular manipulation to do that I am not aware of.

ngx-translate work with **NO Problems on android, on browser and through ionic view**. But Not At All on iOS 11 (can't test on older device). [I tried with a super basic app so that no other module conflict](https://github.com/Gajotres/IonicInternationalization)

Is there *anything* I can do to get my app translated ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found 2 issue that resulted in me loosing so many hours and nerves on this. The basic app I used to test ngx-translate worked on simulator but not device. To make it work on device (ios), I had to change

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http);
}
```

to

```
export function HttpLoaderFactory(http: HttpClient) {
  return new TranslateHttpLoader(http, './assets/i18n/', '.json');
}
```

But the app I needed to translate was already using this ! (more headache) After so many hours lost trying to downgrade everything, everywhere to make it work, I found out the issue was not coming from ngx-translate and iOS but code-push and iOS.

It was silently breaking ngx-translate on device only... I removed it, and surprise, it work.

Comment: Good news! Happy for you

Answer (score 0):

I installed your basic app on my android device and it works fine.

It also works fine on ios simulator (ios 11 - iPhone 8 simulator):

[image: Your app on ios 11 - iPhone 8 simulator]

Can't you have some logs?

Comment: Tried again on the same simulator, no luck. Plugging in safari debugger told me ~"Http failed response for http://localhost:8080/assets/i18n/hr.json: 404 Not found" (may not be exact words). Did you modify anything inside the project ?

Comment: I found out the issue (see answer). Thanks for testing it :) I felt a bit less alone